# search array's keys to get value in php

Tags: php, arrays

this is the array

```
$a = array(
    'blue'=>7, 'red'=>3, , 'green'=>7 );
```

I want to search the arrays's keys with keyword 'green' in order to get the value '7'.
bare in mind that some keys of the same value, but the keys are unique

this doesn't work:

```
echo array_search('green', array_keys($a));
```

i't important to not only determine if the key exits but to actually get the value.
I was sure there is a built in PHP function for it.

Comment: _this doesn't work:_ Well `$a` doesn't contain   `'editingteacher'`

Comment: Perhaps `array_key_exists()` can help. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: `echo $a['green']` didn't do it?

Comment: Or `isset($a['green'])` if you simply want to determine whether that key is set, before you try and access it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with

[**`array_key_exists`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) : (Def) **returns `TRUE` if the given key is set in the array, `key` can be any value possible for an array index.**

See the below example

```
$a = array(
    'blue'=>7, 
    'red'=>3, 
    'green'=>7
);
$val=  (array_key_exists('green',$a))?$a['green']:null;
echo $val;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it like below code in php 7

```
echo $a[$key] ?? 'Not found';
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/946992